# setValue of any view element by pass-by-reference of variable

Tags: android, pass-by-reference

If we have string like

```
String[] buttons_text = {
"One",
"Two",
"Three"
};
```

and Three subsequent buttons for each value of above string.

How to make button's text by passing-reference of buttons_text like &string_text[0],&string_text[1] ?
This is required because, if string value changed from any other method in same context button's text should be changed.

Comment: You can try setting **tag** for buttons and then do logic upon them. post some code for that you're using, i'll suggest solution.

Comment: That will not be possible as you will have to re-draw the view in order to update it. You will always have to call `setText` method of the button. If button text is somehow connected to Editable - then you can use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) to track changes in the String. Otherwise you could use Observer class that would be notified of changes of state of the app and set button texts accordingly

Comment: @Chaosit I thought assigning variable's address is basic feature of Java just like other language like php,c++ and it would make direct accessing value just by referring its address in memory. Any thought why android not support this basic feature? In that case even re-draw wouldn't be necessary right?  
I just made button as example above but it could be any view element like TextView, EditeText.
I will go thorough and see how TextWatcher will be helpful here.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I am playing with basic features in PHP where just echo before and after variable value change was enough and wanted to test same with Java which also worked but failed with android's view elements.

Comment: @kiranking technically you can have pointers to parts of memory. However, the problem is that if you're planning to use native `setText` method - then you'd have to pass a variable with text or resource ID. What can be done is override the rendering process. Since Android won't redraw the view until it is explicitly indicated that the view content is invalid (`invalidate()` method of the View) - you'll have to call this method somehow. But this is done when you call `setText`. The other is to check those variables during each rendering frame (using `Choreographer`) - which is an overkill

Comment: @kiranking I believe that your idea will not work in almost any UI rendering pipeline, unless it rebuilds the whole screen layout on each frame, which I believe, is expensive (no real expertise in the field of rendering - just speculating). And keep in mind that updating text in the UI ALWAYS requires re-drawing of the view.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible in this way. But there is another solution - databinding.

You can have `viewModel` with `ObservableField<String>` for each text property. And your xml view will hold the ref to each like `viewMoldel.text1`. This way each time you change value of String - button text will get updated.

More about databinding: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a job for RecyclerView